# Button/View hides behind the soft keyboard when entering multilines in Edittext in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am new to Android programming and want to understand the following behavior. I have a simple layout with an Edittext and a button as below. When phone is in portrait mode, entering more than 10 lines, does not hide the button behind the keyboard.However, when phone is in landscape mode, entering around 3-4 line, hides the button behind the keyboard.Can anyone help me explain, why this is happneing. And what is the solution so behavior is consistent across orientation?

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|flagNoFullscreen"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
        android:maxLength="480"
        android:maxLines="8"
        android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />   
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="ENTER"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```